# Why is char different from *both* signed char and unsigned char?

Tags: c, integer, standards, type-systems

[cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/arithmetic_types) states that `char` is

> Equivalent to either `signed char` or `unsigned char`  [...], but `char` is a distinct type, different from both `signed char` and `unsigned char`

I assume this means that a `char` can hold exactly the same values as either `unsigned char` or `signed char`, but is not compatible with either.  Why was it decided to work this way? Why does unqualified `char` not denote a `char` of the platform-appropriate signedness, like with the other integer types, where `int` denotes exactly the same type as `signed int`?

Comment: Unlike any other integer type, it's implementation-defined if `char` is signed or unsigned.  Therefore it needs to be handled separately by the specification.

Comment: Of course the specification needs to treat char specially. I believe this still does not explain why an unqualified `char` may not designate the char type of the platform-appropriate signedness.

Comment: @Tau it's a feature of the language, not the system. The reason may be historic: at the time the standard was laid down, different compiler versions may already have been using `char` with different signedness.

Comment: Because it's unknown, the programmers can't assume anything, they must use `char` as a specific individual type. Think about portability, if the programmer assumes that it's signed, then it will break on other systems, and portability is one of the major points of C.

Comment: That's pretty much what `char` *does* do, @Tau.  I guess you're asking about why the spec says "equivalent to" instead of "the same as", but this is mostly technical (with respect to the language of the spec), not of much practical significance.

Comment: But if you want another way to look at it, @Tau, I personally find it helpful (though not altogether accurate) to think of `char` as a type for representing character data, and `signed char` and `unsigned char` as types for representing small integers.

Comment: @JohnBollinger That is not exactly what `char` is. As I already stated in the question, `char` is not **compatible** with `unsigned char` AND not compatible with `signed char`. None of the comments so far explain why it must be so. @Someprogrammerdude Portability is not helped by this either, as `char` already has platform-specific range.

Comment: C could never agree on what `char` is, so gave up entirely and laid down things like `uint8_t` instead, types with *zero* ambiguity. The historical types like `int`, `long` and so on have various reasons why they're so intensely weird at times, but it's too late to change that.

Comment: @tadman I'm not asking to change things, I'm interested in what the reasons *were* : )

Comment: Remember that C was written in an era where an 8-bit "byte" wasn't all that common, considering. The first C compiler was written for the PDP-11 which used 16-bit "words" instead of bytes, where at the time "words" could be all kinds of sizes, on up to the truly bizarre levels. `char` is their best effort to produce something more consistent and able to store the somewhat common, though not entirely ubiquitous, 7-bit ASCII of the time period.

Comment: @Tau, there is no "why it *must* be so".  There are reasons why it *is* so, which you may find either more or less compelling, but language design is a creative process, not a discoverry process.

Comment: @JohnBollinger What were those reasons?

Comment: [continued](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74180152/why-is-char-different-from-both-signed-char-and-unsigned-char#comment130970939_74180152) ... and to get round this the `signed char` and `unsigned char` were introduced for those who need portability, rather than risking breaking older code by strictly defining `char`. For handling just the ASCII range of characters, it probably does not matter.

Comment: But I think the most compelling reasons are related to technical details of what the spec means by "compatible", and the implications on the behavior of the C abstract machine in terms of which the language semantics are defined.  Which largely does come down to a compatibility consideration, though not from the direction you seem to be thinking.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: “I count about six reasons among these comments already”: There is no reason stated in the currently visible comments why the C committee settled on “`char` is a distinct type from `signed char` and `unsigned char`” rather than ”`char` is the same type as an implementation-defined choice of `signed char` or `unsigned char`.” Weather Vane’s comment on defining `signed char` and `unsigned char` to support portability without breaking old code relying on some semantics on `char` hints at a possible reason but does not give one since how this breakage would occur is not stated.

Comment: It might help to find out the effect of `char` being a separate type first.

Comment: @ikegami plain char being a separate type means it is not compatible with the appropriate-signedness-char. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/type#Compatible_types: "If two declarations refer to the same object or function and do not use compatible types, the behavior of the program is undefined."

Comment: Thanks for the info. Unfortunately, it didn't really help.

Comment: The question amounts to this: Why did they decided `char` and `unsigned char` to be incompatible in all environments instead of just some environments. (And similarly for `char` and `signed char`.) That decision could have gone either way, so the answer might only exist in the minds of the committee. But note that the choice they made sounds like the safer of the two options to me.

Comment: Early versions of C did not have the `unsigned` or `signed` keywords. All integer types were signed apart from `char` which depended on the implementation. Rather than dictate that `char` should be signed (which would conflict with existing implementations), two new types were added.

Comment: I'm speculating, but: if the Standard had required, in Eric's phrasing, "`char` is the same type as an implementation-defined choice of `signed char` or `unsigned char`", then if I'm on a platform on which `char` is the same as `signed char`, I can intermix the two with no warnings, and create code that's not portable to a machine where `char` is unsigned by default.  So the definition "`char` is a distinct type from `signed char` and `unsigned char`" helps force people to write portable code.

Comment: @SteveSummit I'd say the three distinct types of `char` *enable* portable code.   "`char` is the same type as an implementation-defined choice of `signed char` or `unsigned char`" would be an actual impediment to portable code for the very reason you described.

Answer (score 7):

## TL;DR

Backwards compatibility. Probably. Or possibly that they had to choose and didn't care. But I have no certain answer.

## Long version

#### Intro

Just like OP, I'd prefer a certain answer from a reliable source. In the absence of that, qualified guesses and speculations are better than nothing.

Very many things in C comes from backwards compatibility. When it was decided that whether `char` would be the same as `signed char` or `unsigned char` is implementation defined, there were already a lot of C code out there, some of which was using signed chars and others using unsigned. Forcing it to be one or the other would for certain break some code.

#### Why it (probably) does not matter

> Why does unqualified char not denote a char of the platform-appropriate signedness

It does not matter much. An an implementation that is using signed chars guarantees that `CHAR_MIN` is equal to `SCHAR_MIN` and that `CHAR_MAX` is equal to `SCHAR_MAX`. Same goes for unsigned. So an unqualified `char` will always have the exact same range as its qualified counterpart.

From the standard [5.2.4.2.1p2](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.4.2.1p2):

> If the value of an object of type char is treated as a signed integer when used in an
> expression, the value of CHAR_MIN shall be the same as that of SCHAR_MIN and the
> value of CHAR_MAX shall be the same as that of SCHAR_MAX. Otherwise, the value of
> CHAR_MIN shall be 0 and the value of CHAR_MAX shall be the same as that of
> UCHAR_MAX.

This points us in the direction that they just didn't really care, or that it "feels safer".

Another interesting mention in the C standard is this:

> All enumerations have an underlying type. The underlying type can be explicitly specified using an enum type specifier and is its fixed underlying type. If it is not explicitly specified, the underlying type is the enumeration’s compatible type, which is either a signed or unsigned integer type (excluding the bit-precise integer types), or `char`.

#### Possible problems with breaking this (speculation)

I'm trying to come up with a scenario where this would actually matter. One that could possibly cause issues is if you compile a source file to a shared library with one compiler using signed char and then use that library in a source file compiled with another compiler using unsigned char.

And even if that would not cause problems, imagine that the shared library is compiled with a pre-ansi compiler. Well, I cannot say for certain that this would cause problems either. But I can imagine that it could.

And another speculation from Steve Summit in comment section:

> I'm speculating, but: if the Standard had required, in Eric's phrasing, "`char` is the same type as an implementation-defined choice of `signed char` or `unsigned char`", then if I'm on a platform on which `char` is the same as `signed char`, I can intermix the two with no warnings, and create code that's not portable to a machine where `char` is unsigned by default. So the definition "`char` is a distinct type from `signed char` and `unsigned char`" helps force people to write portable code.

#### Backwards compatibility is a sacred feature

But remember that the persons behind the C standard were and are VERY concerned about not breaking backwards compatibility. Even to the point that they don't want to change the signature of some library functions to return `const` values because it would yield warnings. Not errors. Warnings! Warnings that you can easily disable. Instead, they just wrote in the standard that it's undefined behavior to modify the values. You can read more about that here: https://thephd.dev/your-c-compiler-and-standard-library-will-not-help-you

So whenever you encounter very strange design choices in the C standard, it's a very good bet that backwards compatibility is the reason. That's the reason why you can initialize a pointer to `NULL` with just `0`, even for a machine where NULL is not the zero address. And why `bool` is a macro of the keyword `_Bool`.

It's also the reason why bitwise `|` and `&` has higher precedence than `==`, because there were a lot (several hundred kilobytes that was installed on three (3) machines :) ) of source code including stuff like `if (a==b & c==d)`. Dennis Ritchie admitted that he should have changed it. https://www.lysator.liu.se/c/dmr-on-or.html

**So we can at least say for certain that there are design choice made with backwards compatibility in mind, that has later been admitted by those who made the choices to be mistakes and that we have reliable sources for that.**

## C++

And also remember that your sources points to C++ sources. In that language, there are reasons that don't apply to C. Like overloading.

Answer (score 7):

The three C character types `char`, `signed char`, and `unsigned char` exist as codification of legacy C implementations and usage.

The XJ311 committee that codified C into the first C standard (now known as C89) stated their [purpose in the **Rational**](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c89/rationale/a.html#1-1) (italics original):

> **1.1  Purpose**
>
> The Committee's overall goal was to develop a clear, consistent, and
> unambiguous Standard for the C programming language which codifies the
> common, existing definition of C and which promotes the portability of
> user programs across C language environments.
>
> The X3J11 charter clearly mandates the Committee to *codify common
> existing practice*. ...

N.B.: the X3J11 committee went out of their way to emphasize they were codifying existing implementations of C and common usage/practices in order to promote portability.

In other words, "standard" C was never **created** - existing C code, usages, and practices were codified.

Per [**3.1.2.5 Types**](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c89/rationale/c1.html#3-1-2-5) of that same **Rationale** (bolding mine):

> Three types of char are specified: `signed`, plain, and `unsigned`.  A plain char may be represented as either `signed` or `unsigned`, **depending upon the implementation, as in prior practice**.  The type signed char was introduced to make available a one-byte signed integer type on those systems which implement plain char as unsigned. ...

The words of the committee are clear:  three types of `char` exist because plain `char` had to be either `signed` or `unsigned` in order to match "prior practice".  Plain `char` therefore had to be separate - portable code could not rely on plain `char` being signed or unsigned, but both `signed char` and `unsigned char` had to be available.

The three character types can not be compatible in any way because of portability concerns - and portability of standard-conforming C code was one of the XJ311 committee's main goals.

If `extern char buffer[10]` were compatible with `unsigned char buffer[10]` on a system where plain `char` is unsigned, the code would behave differently if the code were compiled* on a system where plain `char` is signed and therefore ***in***compatible with `unsigned char buffer[10]`.  For example, bit shifting elements of `buffer` would change behavior depending on whether or not `buffer` were accessed through the `extern char buffer[10]` declaration or the `unsigned char buffer[10];` definition, breaking portability.

The fact that `char` could already be signed or unsigned with different behavior in such a situation **already existed**, and the committee could not change that without violating their goal to "codif[y] the
common, existing definition of C".

But with a goal of promoting portability, there was no reason whatsoever to create a crazed, portability-nightmare-inducing situation where "sometimes `char` is compatible with this and not that, and sometimes `char` is compatible with that and not this".

* - If the code compiled at all - but this is a hypothetical meant to demonstrate *why* the three `char` types **must** be incompatible.

Answer (score 4):

One part of the reasoning for not mandating either signed or unsigned for plain `char` is the [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) code set used on IBM mainframes in particular.

In [§6.2.5 Types ¶3](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p3), the C standard says:

> An object declared as type `char` is large enough to store any member of the basic execution character set. If a member of the basic execution character set is stored in a `char` object, its **value is guaranteed to be nonnegative**.

<sup>*Emphasis added.*</sup>

Now, in EBCDIC, the lower-case letters have the code points 0x81-0x89, 0x91-0x99, 0xA2-0xA9; the upper-case letters have the code points 0xC1-0xC9, 0xD1-0xD9, 0xE2-0xE9; and the digits have the code points 0xF0-0xF9.  So:

- The alphabets are not contiguous.
- Lower-case letters sort before upper-case letters.
- Digits sort higher than letters.
- And because of §6.2.5¶3, the type of plain `char` has to be unsigned.

Each of the first three points is in contradistinction to ASCII (and ISO 8859, and ISO 10646 aka Unicode).

Comment: I just peeked at K&R 1st edition 2.2 which has an amusing summary of different types used by some of the exotic computers back in the 1970s. Not only IBM 370 with EBCDIC, 8 bit char and 32 bit int, but also Honeywell 6000 with 9 bit char and 36 bit int. Computers were still very experimental, so it's perhaps no wonder that the C type system ended up with so much implementation-defined behavior and compatibility concerns.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is backwards compatibility. Here is some research regarding the history behind it. It only uses authoritative first sources like the publications by Dennis M. Ritchie (the creator of C) or ISO.

In the beginning, there was only `int` and `char`. The early draft of C called "NB" for "new B" included these new types not present in the predecessors B and BCPL [Ritchie, 93]:

> ...it seemed that a typing scheme was necessary to cope with characters and byte addressing, and to prepare for the coming floating-point hardware

> **Embryonic C**
>
> NB existed so briefly that no full description of it was written. It supplied the types `int` and `char`, arrays of them, and pointers to them, declared in a style typified by
>
> ```
> int i, j;
> char c, d;
> ```

`unsigned` was added later [Ritchie, 93]:

> During 1973-1980, the language grew a bit: the type structure gained `unsigned`, `long`...

Note that this refers to the stand-alone "type qualifier" `unsigned` at this point, equivalent to `unsigned int`.

Around this time in 1978, *The C Programming Language* 1st edition was published [Kernighan, 78] and in chapter 2.7 mentions type conversion problems related to `char`:

> There is one subtle point about the conversion of characters to integers. The language does not specify whether variables of type `char` are signed or unsigned quantities. When a `char` is converted to an `int`, can it ever produce a negative integer? Unfortunately, this varies from machine to machine, reflecting differences in architecture. On some machines (PDP-11, for instance), a `char` whose leftmost bit is 1 will be converted to a negative integer (“sign extension”). On others, a `char` is promoted to an `int` by adding zeros at the left end, and thus is always positive.

At this point, the type promotion to `int` was what was described as problematic, not the signedness of `char`, which wasn't even specified. The above text remains mostly unchanged in the 2nd edition [Kernighan, 88].

However, the types themselves are described differently between editions. In the 1st edition [Kernighan, 78, 2.2], `unsigned` could only be applied to `int` and was regarded as a qualifier:

> In addition, there are a number of qualifiers which can be applied to `int`’s: `short`, `long`, and `unsigned`.

Whereas the 2nd edition is in line with standard C [Kernighan, 88, 2.2]:

> The qualifier `signed` or `unsigned` may be applied to `char` or any integer. /--/ Whether plain `char`s are signed or unsigned is machine-dependent, but
> printable characters are always positive.

So in between the 1st and 2nd edition, they had discovered a backwards compatibility problem with applying the new `unsigned`/`signed` (now called *type specifiers* and not qualifiers [ANSI/ISO, 90]) to the `char` type, with the same concerns as were already identified regarding type conversions back in the 1st edition.

This compatibility concern remained during standardization in the late 80s. We can read this from the various rationales such as [ISO, 98, 6.1.2.5 §30]

> Three types of `char` are specified: `signed`, plain, and `unsigned`. A plain `char` may be represented as either signed or unsigned, depending upon the implementation, as in prior practice. The type `signed char` was introduced to make available a one-byte signed integer type on those systems which implement plain `char` as unsigned. For reasons of symmetry, the keyword `signed` is allowed as part of the type name of other integral types. Two varieties of the integral types
> are specified: `signed` and `unsigned`. If neither specifier is used, signed is assumed. In the Base Document the only unsigned type is `unsigned int`.

This actually suggests that `signed int` was allowed to make `int` more symmetric with `char`, rather than the other way around.

---

Sources:

- [ANSI/ISO, 90] ANSI/ISO 9899:1990 - Programming Languages - C
- [ISO, 98] [Rationale for International Standard - Programming Language - C, WG14/N802 J11/98-001](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n802.pdf)
- [Kernighan, 78] [Kernighan, Brian W., Ritchie, Dennis M. - The C Programming Language, 1st edition (1978)](https://archive.org/details/TheCProgrammingLanguageFirstEdition)
- [Kernighan, 88] Kernighan, Brian W., Ritchie, Dennis M. - The C Programming Language, 2st edition (1988)
- [Ritchie, 93] [Ritchie, Dennis M. - The Development of the C Language (1993)](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/chist.html)

Answer (score 0):

The line you quote actually does not come from the C standard at all, but is rather comes from the C++ standard.  The website you link to ([cppreference.com](https://cppreference.com/)) is primarily about C++ and the C stuff there is something of an afterthought.

The reason this is important for C++ (and not really for C) is that C++ allows overloading based on types, but you can only overload *distinct* types.  The fact the `char` must be distinct from both `signed char` and `unsigned char` means you can safely overload all three:

```
// 3 overloads for fn
void fn(char);
void fn(signed char);
void fn(unsigned char);
```

and you will not get an error about ambiguous overloading or such.

Comment: The article I quoted very specifically covers the arithmetic types of C. I believe the wording used there appears neither in the C nor the C++ standard. Char types not being compatible still matters in C: for example, calling a function through a value of incompatible function type (e.g. a parameter being char instead of signed char) results in undefined behavior.

Comment: @Tau: that is incorrect as char, signed char and unsigned char in a function call will all be converted to int via default argument promotions (6.5.2.2)

Comment: @Dodd If you are referring to 6.5.2.2.6 (C17, latest draft, I'm poor (: ), that only applies to function values with a type that does not have a prototype.

Comment: Since (non-static) functions can be called from other compilation units that might not have prototypes, it applies to any non-static function.

Comment: @Dodd It applies only when the function is called through a prototype-less declaration. The UB occurs when the prototype of the declaration used (or, for a prototype-less declaration, the promoted type of the arguments) is not *compatible* with the prototype of the function's definition. Which is just one reason that type compatibility is important in C. Another such reason is: The types named in a _Generic selection may not be compatible with each other; so this entire topic is also relevant to C's version of "overloading" (:

Comment: (And sorry for being so nitpicky. I'm just writing a compiler, so I have to be very precise about all this silly Standardese.)