# How did |= change its behavior?

Tags: c++

I just tracked down a bug in some C++ code, and it came down to a behavioral change in a C++ operation.  I am just curious what caused the behavior change, was it a C++ standards change, or a hardware platform change?  Also roasting me that I should have known better because of this reason or that etc are welcome.  :-P

This code:

```
long sam = 0;
sam |= ((char)-1);
std::cout << "sam became " << sam << std::endl;
```

On my `Raspberry PI` with `gcc 8.3.0` that outputs `255`.

On my `AMD Ryzen Threadripper` with `gcc 9.4.0` that outputs `-1`.

Comment: It's implementation-defined if `char` is `signed char` or `unsigned char`. So it's your compiler (and likely platform) that is important.

Comment: No change - the code is buggy since its behavior depends on whether `char` is signed or unsigned, which is platform dependent.

Comment: in debug what's the value of sam? With -Wconversion have you got a diagnosis?

Comment: I will mark it explicitly signed or unsigned and see what happens.  Thanks.

Comment: Probably the difference lies in [whether `char` is signed or unsigned at your platform and compiler settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054939/is-char-signed-or-unsigned-by-default). If you require a certain behavior, then you need to be specific and use `signed char` or `unsigned char` explicitly.

Comment: Probably `char` is `unsigned` on the Raspberry platform, and `signed` in the Ryzen one.

Comment: Behavior confirmed.  If I mark it explicitly as signed char or unsigned char the behavior is the same.  Thanks, not knowing what is going on just is an unnerving feeling.

Comment: Looks to me like the `|=` isn't relevant; you'd see the same thing with `long sam = (char)-1;`. Haven't tried it.

Comment: Well, I would expect the sign extension when doing an assignment from a char to a long, but I did not expect it when I was bit or-ing it in.  I learned something.

Comment: @Joshua Why wouldn't you expect it ? It's an assignment too (`a |= b` <=> `a = a|b`) ! But the cast happens **before** the assignment, and the issue is precisely on the value to assign. `-1` equals `255` if `unsigned` (unsigned integral types overlap).

Comment: @Joshua In general, operands get promoted to be the same type, so `long | char` causes the `char` to be promoted to `long` before the bitwise-or is applied.

Comment: Change `sam |= ((char)-1);` to `sam |= ((signed char)-1);` and then to `sam |= ((unsigned char)-1);`.  Does that change the result on either or both platforms?  Consider this alternative (if suitable for your real use case): `sam |= -1 & 0xFF;`

Comment: Thank you everyone :-)  Makes sense now.

Comment: Interesting how `int` is always `signed int`, `unsigned` is always `unsigned int`, yet `char` is ambiguous as either `signed char` or `unsigned char` based on platform/compiler.

Comment: @franji1 The "ambiguity" is on the signess, just like the *actual* width in bits of `int` (or `long`...) is implementation defined. Note, though, that `char`, `signed char` and `unsigned char` are [different types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74180152/why-is-char-different-from-both-signed-char-and-unsigned-char).

Comment: Apparently a char string such as "Hello World" is an unsigned char pointer in one system and a signed char pointer in another.  Also all the functions which receive char strings are differently signed.  So I am not able to just specify the signed-ness of char everywhere, because some places it needs to be unspecified so that it will flip flop with the function it is being passed to to stay the same.